# Strings and While loops

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I think I'm having trouble with strings and while loops. When I run this program and I type in an action the program does nothing. It doesn't exit, it just sits there. That's why I think it's a problem with my while loop. But I think it could also be with my Strings right before the while loop. Am I declaring those Strings correctly? Or am I comparing them wrong in the while loop or something? Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2tester3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MotorBoat ex3 = new MotorBoat();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Input how fast the motorboat was going: ");
        int s = keyboard.nextInt();
        ex3.ChangeSpeed(s);
        System.out.printf("Input the time the motorboat ran: ");
        int t = keyboard.nextInt();
        ex3.OperatingTime(t);

        // Ask the user what action he or she wants to take
        System.out.printf("If you want your distance travelled type:" + 
                          " distance\n");
        System.out.printf("If you want how much fuel you used type: fuel\n");
        System.out.printf("If you want to refuel type: refuel\n");
        System.out.printf("If you are finished type: done\n");
        System.out.printf("What would you like to do? ");

        // Compares the input with the defined strings and preforms the
        //   the action requested
        String a = keyboard.nextLine();
        String b = "done";
        String c = "distance";
        String d = "fuel";
        String e = "refuel";
        if (a != b) {
            while (a != b) {
                a = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (a == c) {
                    ex3.getDistance();
                }
                else if (a == d) {
                    ex3.getFuelUsed();
                }
                else if (a == e) {
                    ex3.Refuel();
                }
            }
        }
        if (a == b) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since a is not equal to b, what happens?  What branch of the `if` statement gets executed?  Then what happens next?  How many times does `keyboard.nextLine()` get evaluated?  Please **update** the question with a step-by-step analysis of that happens starting with the `if( a!=b)` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a == b` checks whether `a` and `b` are the same object, which isn't always the case for strings. Use `string.equals()` instead.

Also, use variable names you can differentiate between. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc. are *not* good variable names and will frequently confuse you.

That being said, try this:

```
String input = "";

do {
  input = keyboard.nextLine();

  if (input.equals("distance")) {
    ex3.getDistance();
  } else if (input.equals("fuel")) {
      ex3.getFuelUsed();
  } else if (input.equals("refuel")) {
      ex3.Refuel();
  }
} while (!input.equals("done"));

System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the do-while loop! I don't know why I didn't think of that! But that gives a "cannot find symbol" error on "input" in the conditions for " while (!input.equals("done")); "   I'm assuming because input is declared within the do block?

Comment: Probably. Try declaring `String input;` outside of the `do {} while` block and just use `input = keyboard.nexLine();`.

Answer (score 4):

`a == b` does not compare the value of two strings, but rather that `a` and `b` represent the same objects.  Same for `!=`.

You want to use `a.equals(b)` not `a == b`.

Comment: Oh wow, I just learned that, too. That's a little embarrassing haha. I get how the .equals operates kind of like == , but how do I get it to operate like != ?

Answer (score 1):

In java you can't compare strings with == or !=

Use `a.equals(b)` and `!a.equals(b)`

Answer (score 0):

The “==” operator can be used to test primitive values for equality(i.e. int, char, boolean...).

However, when you compare two object reference variables with the "==" operator, you are actually testing whether the two references point to the same object.

```
Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 
Rectangle box2 = box1;
Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30);
```

Comparing:

```
box1 == box2; // true;
```

Comparing:

```
box1 == box3; // false;
```

To compare the contents of the objects use the equals(Object) method, which will return true if two Objects have the same contents.

```
String a = "distance";
String b = "done";
if(a.equals(b)){
  //code...
}
```